# Reset User Prompt After Timeout

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x

I'm working on an issue where I need to execute the following scenario:

I will prompt for a user input to the screen (console window). When the prompt is displayed as a basic Y/N question, I need to either a) accept the user input response to the prompt and move on OR b) wait a preset time and then reset the prompt to a previous value, whichever comes first. Think of a kiosk that needs to reset if the user walks off and you've got the idea.

It seems my logic (pseudo Python below) adds the time delay to the user input after it just sits there waiting on the user to reply rather than giving up on the user after some time and resetting.

```
UserInput = input("prompt. y/n?")
if UserInput == "y":
    Do something to move on
elif UserInput != "y":
    time.sleep(dwell)
    Do something to reset
```

If the user is actively paying attention, then everything I've got now works as it should. But, I have a feeling that everything is hinging on the "Enter" key being pressed to submit the input, and I don't know how to force an override input or simply have the watchdog timeout and move along.

Also, it seems that no user input is accepted during the sleep time. Is that true?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on unix just use the "signal.alarm" function, otherwise you could use something like this code for windows:

```
import msvcrt
import time

def raw_input_with_timeout(prompt, timeout=30.0):
    print prompt,    
    finishat = time.time() + timeout
    result = []
    while True:
        if msvcrt.kbhit():
            result.append(msvcrt.getche())
            if result[-1] == '\r':   # or \n, whatever Win returns;-)
                return ''.join(result)
            time.sleep(0.1)          # just to yield to other processes/threads
        else:
            if time.time() > finishat:
                return None
```

instead of returning "None" you could raise an error or whatever you want...